# Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'. > Changes are not tracked, unable determine incremental changes

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm try to run my flutter application on android mobile but there is showing a errors

flutter run application

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
>
> > Changes are not tracked, unable determine incremental changes.
>
> - Try:
>
> > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> > Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 3m 52s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed
> with exit code 1